# JQuery to reset it self?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So first, I do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form#delete_admire").submit(function() {
// we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
var  deleteIdAdmire    = $('#deleteIdAdmire').attr('value');
var  location = 'li#liadmire_'+ deleteIdAdmire;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../admire/delete.php",
        data: "deleteIdAdmire="+ deleteIdAdmire,
        success: function(){
            $(location).hide(function(){$('div.success2').fadeIn();});

        }
    });
return false;
});
});
```

This works... now for the past hour or so I've been trying to get the 'div.success2' to fade out and to reset the script so when someone clicks the delete again, it will run all over again. I'm very new to JQuery and javascript, I apologize for my probably very stupid question. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: James's answer will work well. You will never have to reload the entire script with jQuery. What made you think you had to?

Comment: When do you want the `$('div.success2').fadeout();` to be called? I Don't see it anywhere in the provided code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason why this code can't run multiple times.  The `fadeOut` can be done very easily:

```
$('div.success2').fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

Replace `5000` with whatever delay you would like before it fades out.

Comment: Wow that was simple! Thank you sir! For some reason, it only allows me to run the script over again once the 'div.success2' as been fully faded out. This was exactly what I was looking for! Enjoy your weekend sir!